# Typescript generic union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a simple switch function which takes a first parameter that must be an union of string & an object which have keys based on the first parameter union and can return any value.

```
export const mySwitch = <T extends string>(value: T, possibilities: {[key in T]: any}): any => {
    return possibilities[value];
};
```

Typical usage would be

```
let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3" = "val1";
// should returns s1
// Impossible should be type-checked as an error since it's not part of the option union type
mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: "impossible"});
```

My problem occurs because the generic type `T` must be a `string` in order to be used as an object key. I don't know how you can tell `T` to be an union of `string`.

I tried `T extends string` with no success.

Comment: What was the problem with `T extends string` ? It disallows `impossible` (I am not sure you want that) but otherwise works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgBU5QZhkATVOdKA5AcwD4AKAG4BDADYBXYAC44NADRxIqVAQBGBUUQLBUMgN4BtANbAscLrIC6M4ciwBfAJQ27FXnD0BYAFBw-cKGAYcShkRQhlNQ0tHQMRCWBLAG4fexTvHx9mYARRYUC4USC4CDAYAhQZACJ4gEYquAAfOBqxACYG5tbRAGYq9Ox8IlJ+UvKUBT066tR6hXi2mY75sR6ZvoUCDCUVVSLqrZ21IqqnJLggA

Comment: I'd probably do it [this way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgGk5QZhkATVOAa2CwgDM4AVADQCAfAAoAUHDgA3AIYAbAK7AAXHBqCpcSKlQEARgQVECwVOv4SAlJYDaNALoURcAN7aowGEqjIdEHqGxqbmdvLKwI4A3BIAvrESCt5wEGAwBCjqAEQRAIzZcAA+cLmKAEyFJWUKAMyFlDUFsUho8GyU2PhEpGJpGSjCHtL5OagFWiMVY5WTsoq1Y-VzBBi6+gbJOavrhsnZ8XBybK3o1tFwAPSXcF4+fmzZ4wdAA) but I think we need a [mcve] here to really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your example uses a type without being initialised. For example initilise option with `"val1"`

Comment: @MathieuUrstein that is a different issue, since you initialize it with a value flow analysis can prove only `val1` is possible regardless of your  type annotation so you will get errors on any prop that is not `val1`. Introduce some uncertainty and the example works:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwMoHcCWVgAsYF4YA8AKjAKYAeUpYAJhDNAE5pgDmAfABQBuAhgDYBXUgC4YRADQwADiAgQ0AIzT8MaUhDEBvANoBrUghgtxAXTG8wCAL4BKC1bzsYWgLAAoGF5iNSUQYxgMnIKyqpQ6hA6fEKkpgDcHtaJ7h78fjAg0hHgYgBEMQCMeTAAPjAFAgBMJeWV-ADMJficOvXFUvU1nTFNpjC89KCQULY6ALK8UFgAdIwggrSck9NzljQgcJy2MABUMFW2ph7DECDpM-wgrJyIqBjYnFk5YFJaRfkQHTAxVZ-dPwEDU+TRgdls8SAA

Comment: Yes but it's exactly what I try to resolve. I try to simplify the switch into a simple function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `T extends string` version seems to work well. It disallows `impossible`, but wouldn't you want to disallow it since if the parameter can never have that value that option would be useless?:

```
export const mySwitch = <T extends string>(value: T, possibilities: {[key in T]: any}): any => {
    return possibilities[value];
};


declare let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3";
mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: "impossible"});
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgBU5QZhkATVOdKA5AcwD4AKAG4BDADYBXYAC44NADRxIqVAQBGBUUQLBUMgN4BtANbAscLrIC6M4ciwBfAJQ27FXnD0BYAFBw-cKGAYcShkRQhlNQ0tHQMRCWBLAG4fexTvHx9mYARRYUC4USC4CDAYAhQZACJ4gEYquAAfOBqxACYG5tbRAGYq9Ox8IlJ+UvKUBT066tR6hXi2mY75sR6ZvoUCDCUVVSLqrZ21IqqnJLggA)

If you want to allow the extra keys you could declare the case object separately (bypassing excess property checks and allowing you to reuse the case object)

```
declare let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3";
const casses = {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: "impossible"}
mySwitch(option, casses);
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgBU5QZhkATVOdKA5AcwD4AKAG4BDADYBXYAC44NADRxIqVAQBGBUUQLBUMgN4BtANbAscLrIC6M4ciwBfAJQ27FXnD0BYAFBw-cKGAYcShkRQhlNQ0tHQMRCWBLAG4fexTvHx9mYARRYUC4USC4CDAYAhQZACJ4gEYquAAfOBqxACYG5tbRAGYq9KQ0eARhZR0KDzrq1HqFeLbpjrmxHum+hQIMJRVVIurN7bUiqvsfbHwiUn5S8pQFEbHURyS4IA)

Or you could change your type a little bit so the generic type parameter is the case object, and the value will the be typed as `keyof T`:

```
export const mySwitch = <T>(value: keyof T, possibilities: T): any => {
    return possibilities[value];
};


declare let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3";
mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: "impossible"});
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgBUA+ACgDcBDAGwFdgAuOAa2BYIAMzg0ANHEipUBAEYE2RAsFS8aASl4tkWCnTgBvALAAoOBbhRgMDlGRSIM+YuWqA2q07AAugG4zAF8A0zMzABNgBDYWazg2GzgIMBgCFF4AIi8ARgy4AB84LPYAJjzC4rYAZgyQ7HwiUgZk1JRJQxzM1FzJLxKust72Kq6ayQIMaVk5BMyJqfkEjMCNPzggA)

Also a better option would be to preserve the type from the case object instead of using `any`:

```
export const mySwitch = <T, K extends keyof T>(value: K, possibilities: T): T[K] => {
    return possibilities[value];
};


declare let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3";
mySwitch(option, {val1: 1, val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: false});  // returns string | number
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DKB3ASxgQAs4BeOAHgBUAaOAaTlBmGQBNU4BrYLCADM4NAHwAKAG4BDADYBXYAC4mDSKlQEARgVlECwVCpoBKYwG1GAXQqi4AbwCwAKDhu4UYDHlRkcdZo6ejAGqOYyCsBWANwuAL6xzi4uHMAIstKecLJecBBgISgqAEQRAIzFcAA+cKVyAEyVNXWyAMzFidj4RKTi+YXIDPblKmUMEfUlqI3jcq1T7QwEGAHaOSqCcqjAcSbRbgD0Bx5ePmhw6FAEyADm1XDI8hhawFBAA)

**Edit:**

To preserve both correct return type and error if there are possibilities not present in union you could use this:

```
const mySwitch = <T extends Record<K, any>, K extends string>(value: K, possibilities: T & Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>): any => {
    return possibilities[value];
};

let option: "val1" | "val2" | "val3" = (["val1", "val2", "val3"] as const)[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]
mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3" });
mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s3", impossible: "" }); //err on impossible
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwMoHcCWVgAsYF4YA8AKjAKYAeUpYAJhDAEqmgBONBA0gDQwCGYCAHw8OZStToxoLNGADmggBQA3XgBsArqQBcMbjAAOICBDQAjNGoxpSEXSQBkjZiDYEAouWCaapAgGtSBBAAMxgiEWEYMFJlUhZBAEpdfgQ8QRgAbwBYACgYApgWUigNFjBDY1MLKygbCABtVU1SAF0AbjyAX07cvLUSmBADOvBdACJmgEZxmAAfGEn1ACZZhaW1AGZZ-EUGjZmeDdWj5u3WvnpQSChEhoBZXigsADoWEA1aRUfnt-4aEBwRSJGAAKhgy0SrTyiFQGGwimGozAPEy0wmEEOMGaywxJ2x6k2GO2MC6iV6sPQmCwiJGaHAqPRi0x4x4OLxrIJW2JnLQcCMJnMAwmszJ7SAA)

Note that because typescript does control flow analysis you need to make sure  `option` is not just types as the actual constant you assign instead of the type annotation you specify

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my post in order to be more precise. I don't want the ìmpossible` key to be correct, I want typescript to show me the error that `impossible` is not part of the option union type. Regarding your first example, I want a value to be checked not just the type. My example initiate the option variable.

Comment: @MathieuUrstein I added a new option, let me know what you think

Comment: I'm sorry but it actually works with `T extends string` I just didn't realise I could not try it with an initialised value. My bad, thanks anyway, you made me realise it.

Comment: @MathieuUrstein you are welcomed, I would still suggest you not use `any`. My last version keeps the correct type from the case object which is better IMO

Comment: What if I wanted to also prevent duplicate keys? E.g. `mySwitch(option, {val1: "s1", val2: "s2", val3: "s2"})` should throw an error.